# Outlook Addin - getCallbackTokenAsync fails- code 9017

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

Our company is using the Office js Rest API (via Outlook 2016) to retrieve a token for given user, and it just started failing. Investigation points to:

```
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function (result)
```

returns error code 9017:

```
{"value":null,"status":"failed","error":{"name": "AccessRestricted", "message": "Internal protocol error: '-2147467259'."}}
```

We have ensured this request is made after

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {...
```

has completed its operations (also this just started breaking for us this week/today).

Any guidance is greatly appreciated.. since this is a 'simple' call w/o any arguments to change the call signature, we're not really sure how to proceed.

Environment info:

- Application: Outlook 2019 V1902 (Build 11328.20438)
- Account: https://outlook.office.com/owa/{myUser}
- Office.js API URL: "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/"

Answer (score -1):

It appears the issue was due to an API error when calling getCallbackTokenAsync - operation returned to normal this morning and we are no longer able to replicate the error.

We're going to chuck this up to an oops at MS. Any additional information regarding this error is much appreciated.

UPDATE: scratch that, error is back, what's going on MS?

Comment: This is unexpected. What is the permission level in your app/apps? We are currently looking into this issue to determine if we can figure out the possible cases where you can get such an error.

Comment: Permission to Read/Write - it seems to have issues few hours a day, back to normail today :(  -- duplicated in our dev environment as well with full access/control

Comment: Which version of Exchange is the user's mailbox connected to (if on-premise), or is it Office 365? In either case, if you see the error again can you collect a Fiddler trace from the client machine and search for a GetClientAccessToken EWS request. If you find the request, look at the HTTP response code and whether the response body contains an error. If the request isn't made, then it could point to a client issue, but I would look for other failing requests in that case because if it's failing from multiple machines at the same time, then it's unusual for it to be solely a client issue.

Comment: Please refer to my post, info ur requeting has already been provided - I have completed your requested task and it reveals the API returning 'AccessRestricted', code '-2147467259' - Please advise.

Comment: I see the client version for Outlook in your post, but not the Exchange version you are using (or if it is O365). Also, to verify, in your Fiddler trace, what was the HTTP status of your GetClientAccessToken EWS request?

Comment: This error occurs for our outlook addin, as well as O365 - essentially the REST service. Please also let me know if you need specifics (and how I can obtain them); also please let me know if there is any information I can gather next time this occurs.

Comment: As for the Status of the API request, Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync returns a status of "failed" - I will attempt to run a fiddler trace next time as well.

Comment: OverMars - A fiddler trace log and the error code through fiddler for that specific HTTP request would be helpful. The status failed should be associated with an HTTP code as well (401/502/,,,) that is what we are looking for too. As for the exchange version, what backend are you connecting to? Is it Exchange Online or OnPrem?

Comment: Thank you much!!! I will provide the trace asap - as for exchange version, we can say for sure it's in ExchangeOnline - will try onPrem as well.

Comment: An update - the company did not allow me to provide fiddler traces (beats me why). I no longer work with that company.